# Artificial Neuron Program

Tags: c++, c

I've been trying to write the code for an artificial neuron with 10 inputs between -1 and 1 with 10 random weights also between -1 and 1 all the values correct to 2 decimal places. Plus 50% of the time the random weights need to be negative. The output needs to be the sum of inputs*weight. The code needs to be written in c programming using Dev-C++

I've read a lot of papers relating to the topic and also I've read some  tutorials on this site yet none were in c language.

Comment: You appear from the text to be interested in C programs but, for some reason beyond my limited comprehension, you've tagged the question `sql-server`, something one wouldn't normally associate with neural nets. Are you sure this is what you intended?

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow. It said at least tag sql-server

Comment: I've tried using arrays for the inputs and weights with a float for the decimals like this float[] inputs = {-1;1} and the same for the weights but it gives an error when I complied saying I need a "(" before [

Comment: If you have a question about a specific piece of code, include that piece in the question itself, together with any compiler messages.

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector of weights, the following function constructs the scalar product of the input and the weights, adds the bias term and passes the result into a sigmoid function (untested):

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>

std::vector<double> weights;  //initialize randomly between [-1,1], last entry contains bias
auto sigmoid=[](double x){return 1.0/(1.0-std::exp(x));};

auto neuron_output(std::vector<double> const& input)
{
     double ret = std::inner_product(input.begin(), input.end(), weights.begin(), 0.0); 
     ret += weights.back(); //add bias
     return sigmoid(ret);   //apply sigmoid
}
```

Comment: why not just `double sigmoid(double x){return 1.0/(1.0-std::exp(x)); }`? What's the advantage of a lambda assigned to a variable respect to a plain function?

Comment: @Emilio Garavalia: I definitely read too much about C++11 :-)

Comment: @Emilio Garavalia: but if you want to have a (small and possibly irrelevant) advantage: you could call `sigmoid` -> `activation`, and then conditionally set the activation function. This you don't have to hard-code the function (of course, the same can be obtained with a class hierarchy as well, but with more typing).